# Metasploit stuck on "Sending backdoor command..."

Tags: metasploit

I am trying to use Metasploit on the Unreal IRCD 3281 backdoor. I have tried with different kinds of payloads but the program gets stuck on the last line:

```
msf exploit(unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor) > set payload cmd/unix/bind_perl
payload => cmd/unix/bind_perl 
msf exploit(unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor) > exploit

[*] Started bind handler
[*] Connected to 10.0.1.50:6667...
[*] Command shell session 1 opened (10.0.10.3:43301 -> 10.0.1.50:4444) at 2015-11-27 00:11:32 +0100
[*] Sending backdoor command...
```

And after this I never get the prompt back. Why does this happen? It seems to me that I get a session and it should work, but then nothing happens.

EDIT

If I wait a couple of minutes then I get this:

```
[*] 10.0.1.50 - Command shell session 2 closed.  Reason: Died from Errno::ECONNRESET
msf exploit(unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor) >
```

But I never get the opportunity to write something in the console before this happens, what is wrong?

Comment: You don't really give us a lot to work with. Have you run packet captures? Can you see the process on the victim's side? Do you know what it means when it says "Sending backdoor command"? Have you tried the Metasploit forums?

Comment: I have ran nmap to see the open ports and the version of unreal irc. I dont know about packet capture or how I can see the process on the victims side.

Comment: knowing how to run packet captures is a necessity when you are trying to learn hacking -  your Kali has Wireshark: love it, learn it, breathe it, know it more deeply than metasploit

Comment: Have you run the id command on the empty prompt? You are not supposed to get any prompt just like meterpreter. As you can see in the output, the session is already established. Running the id command on the empty prompt should tell you the user with which you have got the session.

Comment: I can not run any commands because the console is "stuck", I should at least get the msf prompt back, right?

Comment: The cmd payload don't display any prompt. By stuck do you mean you are not able to input anything? If you can input, type id and press enter.

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure as you don't give much information here, but from the following:

> [*] 10.0.1.50 - Command shell session 2 closed.  Reason: Died from Errno::ECONNRESET
>   msf exploit(unreal_ircd_3281_backdoor) >

I can understand that it is your multihandler is the problem. You need to check your payload and make sure that you have set the correct one (it is different for each OS).

For example for Windows systems:

```
windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
```

For Unix/Linux like systems:

```
generic/shell_reverse_tcp
```

After checking payload, perform again, see what you are getting.

Comment: "connection reset" means the multihandler and fixed by the payload? Can you explain the connections between the 3 to come up with this conclusion? It's not clear in your answer.

Comment: there is not much to explain, it is crystal clear what I said. In simple words I just said he is using the wrong payload for wrong environment. If you don't understand pls refer to metsaploit official documentation and have some reading https://community.rapid7.com/docs/DOC-2227

Comment: It might be clear to you, but it is not clear in your answer. You do not "connect the dots". Linking to the Metasploit documentation repo is not helpful. You have a potential answer here, it just needs some tweaking to make it clear.